# Place div in left bottom corner

Tags: css

I want to place div in left bottom corner. I write css like that:

```
#announcement{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I'm not the master of css and I'm not about this solution...

Comment: change to `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
position: absolute;
```

on `#announcement`. For this to work, you need to make sure the parent element that

```
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

refers to does have either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`.

Setting `position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0` does not change the visual position of your element at all since it means "position it relatively to where it would normally appear zero pixels from the left and zero pixels from the bottom".

Answer (score 1):

use fixed position

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 998;
```

Modify your css code

```
#announcement{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 998;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use absolute position

```
position : absolute;
```

if you want division over the other division than set **z-index** property.